# Intercepting Dynamic Memory Allocation Calls in Mozilla Firefox Web Browser

Tags: linux, firefox, ld-preload

Is there a way to intercept "malloc, realloc, calloc and free" requested operations during Mozilla Firefox execution?
I want to do something like using the LD_PRELOAD approach, where it is possible to intercept memory allocation operations in some applications that use glibc, for example. I want to make a trace for these operations.

I want to this in modern versions of Mozilla Firefox, if it is possible. For example:

> Latest version:  FIREFOX_AURORA_54

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you just need to *trace* library calls and not intercept them in some non-trivial way, you may use [ltrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ltrace). Though, I'm not familiar with this utility, so my examples may be not absolutely correct.

You may run it like `ltrace -e malloc+free gcc` and it will trace calls to these two functions done by `gcc`. But at least on my system this simple approach does not work for Firefox:

```
$ ltrace -e malloc+free firefox
"/usr/bin/firefox" is not an ELF file
```

This happens because `/usr/bin/firefox` is just a shell script that launches real binaries. So we need to use command like this (specify the functions you need to trace, of course):

```
$ ltrace -f -e malloc+free sh /usr/bin/firefox
```

First, you run script as `sh /usr/bin/firefox`, then you need to specify the `-f` option, since you are interested not in calls done by the shell, but by its child processes. You will need to filter an output by PID, though, because here we have calls done by the entire process tree.

Please note, that this output may not be perfectly accurate:

- I hope that since latest `ltrace` release in 2013 nothing significantly changed in dynamic linker that `ltrace` does not know about, but I'm not sure
- in case some `libc` function calls f.e. `malloc`, this call may be performed statically. In that case you probably will not see it in output
- for some functions like `alloca` I suppose no library calls are performed at all
- etc.